# how to change the size of the sci notation above the y axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, font-size

how to change the size of the sci notation above the y axis in matplotlib?

below is basic code and image for four subplots, I cant figure out how to reduce the size of the sci power notation above the y axis.

any suggestions would be much appreciated

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot():
    #plot data
    ax.plot(np.arange(0,10000,100),np.arange(0,10000,100))

    #set label style        
    ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis='y')
    ax.yaxis.major.formatter.set_powerlimits((0,0))

    #format labels/ticks
    ax.tick_params(axis='x',tick1On=True, tick2On=False, label1On=True,
        label2On=False, labelsize=7,color='black')
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', tick1On=True,tick2On=False, label1On=True,
        label2On=False, labelsize=7,color='black')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
plot()

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
plot()

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
plot()

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
plot()

plt.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, wspace=0.15, hspace=0.22)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

adding this line:

```
plt.rc('font', **{'size':'30'})
```

changes the font size above the y axis. 30 makes the text visibly bigger but I assume you want to match with the axis labels etc so you'll need something around 6-8 I expect. This will in fact change other text font size (not the axis labels or tick  labels though).

Comment: Awesome - that does it! I had'nt come plt.rc() . Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The power is represented using `offsetText` attribute of Matplotlib's `AxisArtist` container. To change the font size to `power_fontsize`, you can do

```py
ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(power_fontsize)
```

for each instance of `ax` in your code.